# Modelling interrior smooth or flat, what methods are commonly used?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

This is a bit of an art question rather than a "bug" or "how do I" question. And I'm new to Blender.

I'm building a spaceship interior and naturally, it has a lot of flat surfaces, I'm trying to find the best modeling technique. Going for a bit of a clone wars type of animation style (got a long way to go, still learning the software). From my research I see there are 4ish sort of methods. Here they are with the snapshot below them.

1. Model Flat
   [image]
2. Model Smooth
   [image]
3. Model Smooth with Bevel modifier
   [image]
4. Model Smooth with Subdivision modifier
   [image]
   To phrase this into a question. What would you use for a Sci-Fi interior? Could you use the same method for creating weapons? Are there better methods that I have missed?

One thing I find frustrating is that modifiers are not linked to meshes that are linked. Is there an easy way to change that?

Comment: If you want the dark grey parts to be smooth, I'd use a combination of flat, smooth, and sharp edges. Select an edge, right click it (or left click menu if you have it the other way), then set edge to sharp. You can use them to isolate certain areas to be smooth or sharp. Also you would need to join the wall panels and merge their verts to get the modifiers to look right and connect.

Comment: to add something, for subdivsion modifier, choose your edges, press N and in panel Item, the first panel, go to Edges Data and increase the "Mean Crease" or shortcut shift+E. It makes edges sharper

| Edge Crease:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html

Answer (score 0):

For your scene it doesn’t seem to matter much if it is left as flat, as there aren’t really any curved surfaces. However if there are then I would recommend using smooth with auto smooth turned on (the auto smooth prevents the edges that don’t need to look smooth from being smoothed).
If there are any close up shots or you don’t mind the scene being a more high poly then you can use the subdivision surface modifier. Remember to go into edit mode and select the edges you don’t want to be curved, then click shift+E to increase the crease.
Basically you can use all of the methods you’ve mentioned but you just need to know how to use them properly.